# Throttling event-driven Nodejs HTTP requests

Tags: node.js, http, httprequest, node-request

I have a Node `net.Server` that listens to a legacy system on a TCP socket. When a message is received, it sends an http request to another http server. Simplified, it looks like this:

```
var request = require('request-promise');

...

socket.on('readable', function () {
  var msg = parse(socket.read());
  var postOptions = {
    uri: 'http://example.com/go',
    method: 'POST',
    json: msg,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  };

  request(postOptions);
})
```

The problem is that the socket is readable about 1000 times per second. The requests then overload the http server. Almost immediately, we get multiple-second response times.

In running Apache benchmark, it's clear that the http server can handle well over 1000 requests per second in under 100ms response time - if we limit the number of concurrent requests to about 100.

So my question is, what is the best way to limit the concurrent requests outstanding using the `request-promise` (by extension, `request`, and `core.http.request`) library when each request is fired separately within an event callback?

Request's [documentation](https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback) says:

> Note that if you are sending multiple requests in a loop and creating multiple new pool objects, `maxSockets` will not work as intended. To work around this, either use request.defaults with your pool options or create the pool object with the `maxSockets` property outside of the loop.

I'm pretty sure that this paragraph is telling me the answer to my problem, but I can't make sense of it. I've using defaults to limit the number of sockets open:

```
var rp = require('request-promise');
var request = rp.defaults({pool: {maxSockets: 50}});
```

Which doesn't help. My only thought at the moment is to manually manage a queue, but I expect that would be unnecessary if I only knew the conventional way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to throttle your request right? I have workaround this in two ways, but let me show you one patter I always use. I often use `throttle-exec` and `Promise` to make wrapper for `request`. You could install it with `npm install throttle-exec` and use Promise natively or third-party. Here is my gist for this wrapper https://gist.github.com/ans-4175/d7faec67dc6374803bbc

How do you use it? It's simple, just like ordinary request.

```
var Request = require("./Request")
Request({
    url:url_endpoint,
    json:param,
    method:'POST'
})
.then(function(result){
    console.log(result)
})
.catch(reject)
```

Tell me after you implement it. Either way I have another wrapper :)